# Can't test my app on IOS using Expo.io. Cannot find module hashAssetFiles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I’m new to expo.io and I’ve created a simple app using Expo XDE. I’m using a windows 10 PC and testing via QR with an IPhone 6S and a Galaxy S8.

The problem is that I can’t test my app on the iPhone because it throws an error saying “Cannot find module project route/node_modules/expo/tools/hashAssetFiles. Meanwhile, on the Galaxy S8 works perfectly!

[Error image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uerc6.png)

Does anyone know how can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this occurs when you don't have expo installed as a dependency in your node_modules and package.json, you have the wrong version of a package installed, or you have it installed in the wrong section. Make sure your expo dependencies are under dependencies and not under dev-dependencies.

Reference: [Github Issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/72)

Comment: I have expo dependencies under dependencies not in dev dependencies but still getting same error,